# How to automatically launch browser when rails server starts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, puma

Is there a way of automatically launching your browser and pointing it to `http://localhost:3000` when you run `rails server`?

And secondly ensuring this only happens in development?

I would have thought that [Launchy](https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy) would have done the trick, but I'm struggling to work out where to put it.

I've tried adding an initialiser `config/initializers/launchy.rb`

```
require 'launchy'
Launchy.open("http://localhost:3000")
```

And this triggers the browser to open, create a new tab and visit `http://localhost:3000` as expected, however it runs before the server / application has finished booting and I get a ***Cannot connect to Server*** error in the browser.

If I reload in the browser my app works just fine so I'm confident it's not a problem with my app, rather the timing of the `Launch.open` call.

I tried renaming `launchy.rb` to `z_launchy.rb` so it gets loaded last as per the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files) but still the same problem. Launchy fires before the Application is ready for it.

I've also tried adding the code to `config/puma.rb` (I'm using [puma](https://github.com/puma/puma) as my server), to `config/enviroments/developoment.rb` but always the same problem. The `Launchy.open` command gets called to soon.

Where should I call `Launchy.open("http://localhost:3000")` to ensure that a) It runs after the application has loaded and is ready to receive requests; and b) So it only runs in development, not in test or production?

System set up OS X 10.11.3, Rails 4.2.5, ruby 2.2.1p85, puma version 2.15.3

Comment: [From the Rails doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files): _Some parts of your application, __notably routing__, are not yet set up at the point where the after_initialize block is called._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting it into `config.ru` would work, after the `run Rails.application` line. By the time that returns, your app is ready to go. To run it only in `development`, check the `Rails.env`.

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)
run Rails.application
Launchy.open("http://localhost:3000") if Rails.env.development?
```

This is easy, but it feels dirty to me to have this sitting in your app. Better would be a small script that starts your server, waits a moment, then launches the browser.

Comment: `"http://localhost:#{Rails::Server.new.options[:Port]}"` to respect `-p 3001` etc.

Comment: Runs too early for me.  `run Rails.application` returns immediately; only after config.ru finishes do I get to "Puma starting in single mode..." which takes a couple more seconds...